# How to disable locales redirect in yii2-localeurls for specific controller/module

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using [yii2-localeurls](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls) to get along with locales in Yii2. All is working pretty fine. By reading the documentation, you see, redirecting to a configured language or to default language happens automatically (even if `enableLanguageDetection` is `false`). I created a [ticket@github](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls/issues/25) to ensure this functionality is coming soon.

#### So here is my fine `main.php` configuration:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'codemix\localeurls\UrlManager',
    'languages' => [
        'en' => 'en-gb',
        'de' => 'de-de'
    ],
    'enableLanguageDetection' => false,
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [

    ],
],
```

#### Default language configuration in `main.php` according to [$language](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$language-detail) :

```
'language' => 'en-gb',
```

Now, I created a module for a API case which route like the following. Where `api` route-param is mapping to my `API` Module:

#### API module Route

`application.com/api/<controller>/<action>`

#### Module class

```
//namespace define
namespace app\modules\api;

use Yii;

/**
 * Class api
 *
 * @package app\modules\api
 */
class api extends \yii\base\Module
{

    // ####################################### Class attributes // #####################################################

    /**
     * Controller namespace
     * @var string
     */
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\api\controllers';


    // ########################################## Class methods // #####################################################

    /**
     * Init API module
     */
    public function init()
    {
        //call parent class init
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

I don't want to yii2-localeurls redirect to a locale if API module is called. Can't find any information about disable redirect for a specific `module`, `controller` or a `route`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update / Answer:

[yii2-localurl](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls)  now allows to define `ignoreLanguageUrlPatterns` to exclude routes from locale matching. See the [Documentation](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls#excluding-routes--urls).

In my case, i'd like to ignore `/api` from being transformed by localurl's. My `yii2 config` looks like following. It works like a charm.

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'codemix\localeurls\UrlManager',
        'languages' => [
            'en' => 'en-gb',
            'de' => 'de-de'
        ],
        'enableLanguageDetection' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [

        ],
        // Ignore / Filter route pattern's
        'ignoreLanguageUrlPatterns' => [
            '#^api/#' => '#^api/#',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2):

At this point it doesn't look like the component you mention actually supports this kind of behavior. So I'm afraid there's no easy answer to that question (at least not that I can think of).

However...
Since URL parsing is done fairly early in the entire process it leaves you a bit in a pickle. There is only one spot where you can hook into before you get to the parsing: "beforerequest".

So the only way out I see here is to add a second (regular) `urlManager` in your configuration that works for the API and swap them out whenever you detect an API request.

The way to do this is +- like this:

```
'components' => [
    'apiUrlManager' => [
        'class'             => '\yii\web\UrlManager',
        ...
    ]
]
```

Also add this in the configuration (top level):

```
'on beforeRequest' => function($event) {
    if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) == '/api/')
        \Yii::$app->set('urlManager', \Yii::$app->get('apiUrlManager'));
},
```

Whenever a request comes in for the api, it will use the regularly configured component for URL parsing and skip the language detection etc.

It works, but whether it's the best method? I'll leave that up to you.
Or you could always add a feature request to add ignore routes support to the localeurls-component :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about a solution like that, but .. I started a Pull request to make filters work: https://github.com/linslin/yii2-localeurls/commit/52cabfee3024254ae1f905db6d16a9f049dc244f.

Comment: Obviously adding the functionality yourself via a pull request is even better.  :) It actually is valid functionality, you should be able to exclude certain routes.